# How to use robolectric to test activity with extra intent data

Tags: java, android, testing, robolectric

I have an activity LoanDemandEntry.class

I am taking index from intent

```java
selectedMemberIndex = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("selectedMemberIndex");
```

but when I run robolectric test to see if the views exist it will fail because of this line of code.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How does the test fail? Can you add details to your question please?

Answer (score 0):

Just pass your parameter before run your test like this:

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

    Intent mIntent = new Intent(ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext(), YourActivity.class);
    mIntent.putExtra("selectedMemberIndex", 10);

    mActivity = Robolectric.buildActivity(YourActivity.class, mIntent).create().resume().visible().get();
}
```